# css, Wrap element tightly around unspecified number of images

Tags: html, css

I have an element that displays images. This element needs to grow horizontally with the number of images. I do not know beforehand how many images there will be.

My problem is that the element is too wide when there are few images. It does not wrap closely enough around the images.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXgzn/ (The first example works, the second does not.)

```
<div class = "outer">
  <img src = "xx" class = "inner" />
  <img src = "xx" class = "inner" />
  <img src = "xx" class = "inner" />
</div>
```

Comment: Would a min-width be helpful for you?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yesxB/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set either `display:inline-block` or `float:left` on your outer div.

Float **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MAq39/)**

Inline-block **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bxRgx/)**

Positioning them absolutely will also shrink wrap them but usually requires additional position rules (top, left, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:inline-block` to the container to shrink-to-fit, then add `font-size:0` to collapse the surrounding whitespace: [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/sXgzn/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on both the outer and inner elements. Do you need to enforce a max-width?

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://www.bostonbakesforbreastcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sun.jpg" class="inner" />
  <img src="http://www.bostonbakesforbreastcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sun.jpg" class="inner" />
  <img src="http://www.bostonbakesforbreastcancer.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/sun.jpg" class="inner" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer{
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.inner {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

[Fiddle fork.](http://jsfiddle.net/yesxB/1/)