# Wrap element around images regardless of screen size

Tags: jquery, html, background-color, css

This is similar to my earlier question [css, Wrap element tightly around unspecified number of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344448/css-wrap-element-tightly-around-unspecified-number-of-images), but I realized that I have an extra requirement.

I have an element that displays images. This element needs to grow horizontally with the number of images. I do not know beforehand how many images there will be.

Also, if the screen is smaller than max-width of the element, then the images should go to the next line AND the outer element should shrink accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/sXgzn/14/ illustrates the issue.

**Edit: clearer fiddle of desired result:** http://jsfiddle.net/sXgzn/23/

```
<div class = "outer">
  <img src = "xx" class = "inner" />
  <img src = "xx" class = "inner" />
  <img src = "xx" class = "inner" />
</div>
```

From Fiddle : Make screen smaller so there are only 2 suns in the top row. The black background should continue to wrap around the images without extra black on edge.

Edit: just to be clear: With 2 on top and 1 on the next row: it's OK to have black space beneath the second image. I just do not want the wide black right edge.

Comment: Show us what you've tried please.

Comment: If it's working, than what's your question

Comment: ur jsfiddle code is working fine i suppose, the fourth image goes to next line

Comment: "AND the outer element should shrink accordingly."

Comment: okey for backgroud part try wrapping each image in a div and give that div class="inner", remove  background:black; from outer and put it for the inner class.. something like  .outer{
    
    padding:10px;
max-width:320px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.inner{
    width:100px;
    background:black;
}

Comment: @Itay he wanted that when the elements wrap, say 2 on top and 1 shifted below, so the 4th block which is empty shouldn't have black color...

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think he thought on the EDGE, not the AREA (actually I'm pretty sure.)

Comment: made an edit: "just to be clear: With 2 on top and 1 on the next row: it's OK to have black space beneath the second image. I just do not want the wide black right edge."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For I did not found a proper solution to this problem  you could do it using JavaScript and a bit of jQuery:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AKoq/9/edit)**

**HTML example:**

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="img1.jpg" />
  <img src="img2.jpg" />
  <img src="img3.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.images{
  background:#000;
  font-size:0;
}

.images img{
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  background:#000;
  margin:5px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $img = $('.images img'),
    n = $img.length,
    w = 100;  // img width + margins

$(window).resize(function(){  
  var W = $('body').width(), 
      s = Math.min(~~(W/w)||1, n);
      $('.images').width(s*w);
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution.  If you float the outer wrapper left or right then it will snap to the outer bounds of the inner images, but you'll still get a problem with the wrapper extending beyond the width of the inner images when they collapse down.

For example:

```
.outer
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

You'll also have to clear any elements that you don't want jumping up next to the `.outer` div when it's at maximum width;

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add `width:100%`,`min-width:120px`,`max-width:328px`,`box-sizing:border-box`

```
.outer {
    background:black;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    min-width:120px !important;
    max-width:328px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

The outer div will eat up the whole `width` of the parent div but has a `max-width` of `328px`

check demo:

(NOTE!! In the demo the outer div is inside `div#demobody` to simulate the adjustment. Adjust the `width` of `#demobody` and click run to see the difference.)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sXgzn/18/)** (if screen is below 328px)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sXgzn/24/)** (if screen is more than 328px)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sXgzn/20/)** (if screen is 225px)

Comment: This is not dynamic, adjust the window size = nothing happens.

Comment: Its really hard to illustrate window size adjustment in a fiddle you know that's why I made the `div#demobody`. Adjust the width of `div#demobody` and click run to see "DYNAMICNESS".

Comment: in the 2nd demo you have the extra black area on the right side

Comment: Tried this out on my real case. It still has the extra black edge: same as if you take your demo 2 and then push in the screen to make the image go to the next line.

Comment: @user984003 i think there is no way of removing the extra black edge unless the width is computed like maybe using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
.outer {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 15px;
    max-width:360px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.inner {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -5px 0 -5px -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dagobald/7D5jr/

Comment: As per OP request he needs the background on the `.outer`, not on the images.

Comment: I don't see anything regarding that need.

Comment: "*made an edit: "just to be clear: With 2 on top and 1 on the next row: it's OK to have black space beneath the second image. I just do not want the wide black right edge." – user984003 1 hour ago*"

Comment: Yes, in my opinion that simply means, that (s)he doesn't want to stretch the background of the outer container if only one image floats to the next row (empty right bottom corner). I do not see any reason why it should matter which element is colored.

Comment: Did you read? **it's OK to have black space beneath the second image** `CORNER != BORDER`

Comment: Yes, I **did** read and I came to another conclusion. So what? Let the user decide!

Comment: I agree, what he wants is pretty tricky and might result in a xBrowser mess